# Navigation Bar Height and Custom Buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

Can I increase the height of Navigation Bar in iPad and add some custom buttons ? If yes - how ?

Please help !!

EDIT : Actually in my app I have a TopBar thing which contains 4 buttons. I am using animation to switch between views and I want that TopBar to be static in whole app.

I want to create this type of top bar ant throughout whole app the bar should be static and the views I am animating using gestures.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are only 4 views then you can create a custom view for your requirement. you just need to do hide-unhide for all the views.Just add the topbar on main window and make you views frame some smaller it will be static in whole app.

Comment: Thanks Rahul but Can't I do it using NavigationBar ?

Comment: Well no cause when you push a viewController the bar will change it's buttons.If you post some screenshot of the requirement it is easier to help.

Comment: Please look at the EDIT part. :-)

Comment: @Akshay Thakur you can achieve this functionality like this. First viewController which will be displayed will have the top bar. All the view will be blank only topBar as shown in the screenshot will be there. So below the top bar you will add yourViewController's view and manually set the frame. When you tap on another button remove the previous view from superview and add the tapped button view. Ok one query do you have more than 4 views?

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you are looking for is a tab bar with the buttons on the top, instead of the bottom.

You could subclass the `UITabBarController`, hide the default tabbar buttons and add this view with the buttons with the desired position.